# File not found exception when function is called in a different class

Tags: java

I have a function in a class to read a configuration file. When I run it on its own, it would output (using println) the values that I need from said file. However, when I call it in another class to use the values as parameters for a database connection, I get a file not found exception.

I can get it to work if I set the absolute file path from my system (i.e. D:/File/HereIsTheFile/config.properties) but if I package it and deploy then it's completely useless.

Here is the config reader:

```
public class RetConfig {
    public static String retConfig(String param) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try  (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("resources/config.properties")) {
            prop.load(input);
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("url"));
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("user"));
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("password"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return prop.getProperty(param);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(retConfig("url"));
    }
}
```

Here is the function in another class:

```
public static List<MyDataType> retSalesShipOem(String queryInput) throws SQLException {
    List<MyDataType> dataList = new  ArrayList<>();
    try (Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(RetConfig.retConfig("url"), 
                                                                    RetConfig.retConfig("user"),
                                                                    RetConfig.retConfig("password"))) {
        try (Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement()) {
            try (CachedRowSet crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet(); ) {
                crs.setCommand(queryInput);
                crs.execute(conn);
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                while(crs.next()){
                    /*
                     *
                     */
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }       
    return dataList;
}
```

Here is the stack trace (multiple errors but all similar)

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\config.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at kpiDBAccess.RetConfig.retConfig(RetConfig.java:15)
    at kpiDBAccess.EnterD.retSalesShipCyo(EnterD.java:81)
    at javascriptChartData.JSDCSales1C.formatChartDataCYO(JSDCSales1C.java:48)
    at javascriptChartData.JSDCSales1C.doGet(JSDCSales1C.java:216)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where's your stack trace ?

Comment: Updated the question for you, if that's what a stack trace is :) Sorry, still new

Comment: Thanks. And yes, that's exactly what a stack trace is. It's called that because each function adds an entry to the stack, so tracing back along the stack gives you the sequence of calls that got you to where you crashed.

Comment: Seems it's crashing in `retSalesShipCyo`, not `retSalesShipOem`.

Comment: Also , please explain in detail what you mean by " run it on its own ".

Comment: If I call the function in the main from the class, I get the console to log the values in the file. Also, retSalesShipCyo is the exact same code, just with a different while loop

Comment: Throw it all away and use `ResourceBundle`. You don't need to load the same file three times to get three different parameters out of it.

Comment: I agree with EJP, your code is opening a new Inputstream each time you call RetConfig.retConfig. I would recommend returning either the properties object itself or initializing the properties and accessing it a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have restructured the classes and methods to do quick test, I was able to read the `resources/config.properties` entries just fine.

resources/config.properties

```
url:www.google.com
user:bob
password:xxx
```

Reading the File:

```
public class RetConfig {     
    String urlValue;
    String userValue;
    String pwdValue;

    public void retConfig( ) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try  (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("resources/config.properties")) {
            prop.load(input);
            this.urlValue = prop.getProperty("url");
            this.userValue = prop.getProperty("user");
            this.pwdValue = prop.getProperty("password");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the #1 class to access the properties.

```
public class CallRetConfig {
    public static void callerMethod(){
        RetConfig retConfig = new RetConfig();
        retConfig.retConfig();
        System.out.println(" print in second class : "+retConfig.urlValue);
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        callerMethod();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 print in second class : www.google.com
```

Comment: I've tried this and it works, it looks like I need to check the code in my other classes and see exactly why it can't find the file path.

Comment: @E.Ancuta: please accept the answer if this helped. thank you and good luck.

Comment: It answers my question but that's because I didn't know what the issue was when I made it. It turns out that there is a problem with obtaining the file path for the config file if I call the function in my currently existing classes, but if I make a new class it works just fine. It might be a package issue, but I will accept your answer